# Scanner inside while loop

Tags: java, random, while-loop

I need to create a simple game where a random number is created, and the user has to guess the number by inputting numbers into a scanner. If their guess is too high, the system tells them to guess lower, and the same if it is too low.

I'm using a while loop, but I don't know how to continuously call the scanner so that the user can keep guessing. Here is my code so far:

```java
public static void highLow()
{
  Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  int num = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
  boolean loop = true;

  while(loop)
  {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
    int numGuess  = scanner.nextInt();
        if (numGuess > num)
          System.out.println("Guess lower!");
          scanner.nextInt();

        if (numGuess < num)
          System.out.println("Guess higher!");
          scanner.nextInt();

        if (numGuess == num)
          System.out.println("Correct! You win!!!");
          loop = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i use java scanner in while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284949/how-can-i-use-java-scanner-in-while-loop)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! FYI, if you're learning Java, you might want to check out [codereview.se] where you can get lots of tips for improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Here are some suggestions:

1. Assign the input of the `Scanner` back into `numGuess` in order to have the value "ready" for the next loop iteration.
2. Use braces after your `if` conditions.
3. You don't have to redeclare the `Scanner` object each time. Do it once, before the loop.

It was a combination of #1 and #2 that was causing your code to fail before. Look closely at your `if` blocks. If you leave off the braces, only the **first** line following is part of the `if`. (see [Is it ok if I omit curly braces in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020228/is-it-ok-if-i-omit-curly-braces-in-java))

So, you meant this:

```
if (numGuess == num)
    System.out.println("Correct! You win!!!");
    loop = false;
```

But what the compiler "saw" was really this:

```
if (numGuess == num)
    System.out.println("Correct! You win!!!");
loop = false;
```

The misplaced `loop = false` will ensure that your loop only ever runs once, no matter what the user entered. Explicitly including braces keeps it unambiguous!

Here's what your code looks like after making the above changes:

```
public static void highLow()
{
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int num = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
    boolean loop = true;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numGuess = 0;

    while(loop)
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        numGuess  = scanner.nextInt();
        if (numGuess > num) {
            System.out.println("Guess lower!");
            numGuess  = scanner.nextInt();
        } else if (numGuess < num) {
            System.out.println("Guess higher!");
            numGuess  = scanner.nextInt();
        } else if (numGuess == num) {
            System.out.println("Correct! You win!!!");
            loop = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixed a lot of issues. However, now when I first input a number, the scanner says for example "Guess lower!", with a scanner box underneath. I input another number, and instead of registering, it loops back to the beginning and asks me to input a number. Is there any way to do this with only 1 scanner box appearing?

Comment: Try moving the first `System.out.print` line from inside the loop to just before the loop, so it only is executed once.

Comment: It still looks like this...   I have to put in the number twice for it to register                                                                             Guess higher!
 [DrJava Input Box]  7
 [DrJava Input Box]  7                                                                                            Guess lower!

Comment: Oops, sorry, in my previous comment I meant to say: move the first *two* lines of the loop outside. :)

Comment: ahhhhhh... That makes much more sense! Thanks for your help! :D

Comment: No problem! Glad to help! Here's an upvote for you, so you can get closer to upvoting my answer as well ;)