# Java application that will listen for user input in a loop without pausing

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, input, command-line-interface

For simplicity, I'm looking to have looping logic in the terminal that will continually process information while checking for user input without waiting for user input.

pseudo:

```
loop 
    If user input
        See what they've entered
    Do logic loop
```

Note: I've tried using a scanner with System.in and attempting to see if the next line was empty. Unfortunately, that implementation still causes the application to pause.

Comment: Start a second Thread with the Scanner waiting for input on that Thread.

Comment: Like @camickr mentioned - Is your motivation for this solution to have the application continue running, so the user will not experience a pause while waiting for input? if that is the case - then an input handling thread like the one suggested above would work like a charm.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a comment from [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) and the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284949/how-can-i-use-java-scanner-in-while-loop),  you can use the following algorithm:

```
     public class ScannerRunner implements Runnable {
         private Scanner sc;
         private ScannerRunner() {/* no instantiation without parameters*/}
         public ScannerRunner(Scanner sc) {
            this.sc = sc;
         }
         @Override
         public void run() {     
            System.out.println("Enter The Correct Number ! ");
            int question = sc.nextInt(); 

            while (question!=1){
               System.out.println("please try again ! ");
               question = sc.nextInt(); 
            }
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
     }
```

Then, create a scanner in you main thread, then spawn a thread using the above Runner (constructed with the scanner you provided), and have your main thread listen to inputs on the scanner. The [Scanner API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) should help you out.