# How to implement infinite for loop in array list if size is not specified

Tags: java, arraylist

I've tried the following but am not getting any output:

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList ();
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter string  "+(i+1));
    String se = s.next();        
    list.add(se);
}

for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.print(list.get(i));
}
```

Comment: You can't use a for-loop on the list's size for the purpose of creating the list in the first place.  You need to have some other control mechanism, such as a while-loop that continues until the user enters some sort of "finished" value.

Comment: i don't actually know how to use while here actually i am new to array list

Comment: Using a while loop has nothing to do with ArrayList.  Imagine that you have a program that reads user input and prints it out, and keeps going until the user enters a special value like "done" or "stop".  Just, instead of printing the values out, add them to the list instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i use java scanner in while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284949/how-can-i-use-java-scanner-in-while-loop)

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop on your `Scanner` input until you get an empty line, not on your `List`. Your `List` is empty to start with so you will not enter your loop.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

int counter = 1;
String userInput;
System.out.println("Enter string "+ counter);
while (true) { // Infinite loop, you need a break inside of the loop to get out of it
    // Assign the input value to the userInput variable
    userInput = s.nextLine();
    // Stop looping when it is an empty line
    if (userInput.isEmpty()) {
        break;
    }

    list.add(userInput);
    counter++;
    System.out.println("Enter string "+ counter);
}

for (String st : list) {
    System.out.println(st);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
here the size is specified by the user...
now it works...

 ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList ();
         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("How many strings to add");
            int a = s.nextInt();
            for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter string  "+(i+1));
                String se = s.next();        
                list.add(se);
            }

            for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
            {
                System.out.print(list.get(i));
            }
```

Comment: i don't actually wants to get size from user i want to make it infinite

Comment: It will not work, you have to change in first loop i<list.size to i < a

Comment: To make it “infinite” you need a while-loop as others have said.

Comment: OK thanks yes that was done by mistake .i have corrected that .

Comment: @TeekhiiMirchii You want an infinite user-input loop that collects all inputs and stores them in a list?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not getting any output is because you are using `list.size()` as a comparison value in a loop before you've populated the list with elements. It is empty so it's size will always be `0` until you add some elements to it.

> Returns the number of elements in this list. If this list contains more than Integer.MAX_VALUE elements, returns Integer.MAX_VALUE.

The quote above is from the List [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size()). Keep in mind that it's always a good idea to read the documentation of new concepts you are trying to use.

> You can't use a for-loop on the list's size for the purpose of creating the list in the first place. You need to have some other control mechanism, such as a while-loop that continues until the user enters some sort of "finished" value.

So instead of using the list size *(like the comment above states)* you should be using another control mechanism like a local variable which can define the size of your list. It can also be used to set the initial capacity of your list.

```
    // Use this local variable as a control mechanism
    final int listSize = 10;

    // Create new array with the initial capacity set to 10
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(listSize);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Use a dedicated integer value for the loop
    for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter string  " + (i+1));
        String se = s.nextLine();
        list.add(se);
    }

    // Once the list has been populated we can use it's
    // size as a comparison value in a loop
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        // Print each string in a new line
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
```

Couple of notes that might help you in the future:

- Use `System.out.println` instead of `System.out.print` whenever you want to print each log in a separate line.
- Format your code in a readable manner so it's easier for both you and others to review it. In my opinion this includes separating each element in a syntax with at **least** a single whitespace as well as following the proper naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

First loop in your code tries to iterate over values between 0 and *list.size()* - also 0, because your list is empty.

In this example your program will keep asking for string unless user provide *STOP_WRITING_CODE* value which is **exit**.

```
static final String STOP_WRITING_CODE = "exit";

ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList();
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
String se = "";

while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter string: ");
    se = s.next();
    if(se != STOP_WRITING_CODE)
        break;

    list.add(se);
}

for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print(list.get(i));
}
```